# How can i fill all the screen with canvas

Tags: android, colors, background, android-canvas

I have a canvas but by some reason this don´t fill all the screen. A white border appears in the screen. I need that black canvas background fill all the screen.

[image]

How can i solve this?

This is my actual code:

```
package com.simmaro.pruebas_canvas_2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Duda resuelta en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250143/how-to-insert-an-image-with-canvas/27251423#27251423     
        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        Lienzo image = new Lienzo(this);
        //Finalmente se añade el Lienzo al layout
        layout1.addView(image);     
    }

}


//Modo 2
class Lienzo extends View {
    private Drawable theimage;

    public Lienzo(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Width
        int ancho=canvas.getWidth();
        //Height
        int alto=canvas.getHeight();
        //Canvas background color
        canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,(ancho-48)/2,(alto-48)/2,null);   
    }
}
```

Edit: This is the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.simmaro.pruebas_canvas_2.MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show the layout file (activity_main)...

Comment: Is your question about hiding "Pruebas_canvas_2" title? That is about android actionbar,and you can hide that with using following code on your **"OnCreate method"** `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the layout as below:
The issues is due to paddings it is not filling totally

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.simmaro.pruebas_canvas_2.MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from your base RealativaLayout, you set padding to it so added child views will respect them. Remove them to get a fullscreen canvas :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```